# how to sort this array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

this is my array and I'm try to send email skills of user, but email is repeating,

```
abc@yahoo.com | Angular JS
abc@yahoo.com |  JQuery

efg@gmail.com  |  Linux
efg@gmail.com  |  JQuery
efg@gmail.com  | Angular JS

xyz@esapienz.com  |  JQuery
xyz@esapienz.com  |  Angular JS

pqr@esapienz.com |  Linux
pqr@esapienz.com  | Microsoft Dot Net
pqr@esapienz.com  | Angular JS
```

but I want to split array as order by email-id

```
abc@yahoo.com | {Angular JS, JQuery}

efg@gmail.com  |  {Linux, JQuery, Angular JS}

xyz@live.com  |  {JQuery, Angular JS}

pqr@live.com |  {Linux, Microsoft Dot Net, Angular JS}
```

please help, thanking in advance...

Comment: provide your php array here

Comment: first array is my mysql array (this is my ...) after this line

Comment: This array is not valid, because you are always overvriting the same key. Do you mean, is it a result set of you query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be precise : you want to "group", not to "sort"
Here is an example :

```
$newArray = [];
foreach($your_array as $row){
  // [0] gets email, [1] gets skill
  $newArray[$row[0]][] = $row[1];
}

ksort($newArray);
```

Comment: yes I want to "group"